# split and extract same function

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I work on Google spreadsheets and I only need to keep the status (see below) such as "rejected, offer, New .." as well as the date of the specific status. And so in 2 different columns.

I can do it with multiple formula such as `split` and `left` but that is a lot of manual work (all the text below is in one cell).

Would anyone have an idea on how to automatize this through a single formula?

Example:

```
column             
New (status in column 1)       YYYY (date in column 2)
Interview                      YYYY
Rejected                       YYYY
```

"Rejected on Date: 11/11/2016 6:23:33 AM and Modified by: YYYY|| Offer on Date: 6/2/2016 5:36:04 AM and Modified by: YYYY|| Interview on Date: 4/14/2016 2:30:57 AM and Modified by: YYYY|| New on Date: 4/14/2016 2:24:58 AM and Modified by: YYYY|| To be Hired on Date: 6/7/2016 11:03:58 AM and Modified by: YYYYY|| Pending Contract Approval on Date: 6/7/2016 4:56:55 AM and Modified by: YYYY|| Interview on Date: 5/10/2016 12:40:30 AM and Modified by: YYYY|| Interview on Date: 4/27/2016 8:57:31 AM and Modified by: YYYY"

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I quite don't get it, it is not very clear. What have you done so far so we can help you, have a look also at [how to ask questions on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can clarify your question. For example, is the data you want to parse located in a single string of character or located in different cells ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The text in between " " is what I get in a cell. From this, I only want to extract specific information: Status & date for each update. It represents all the updates for a specific requisition. In essence, I would like to have it in a column type format, only keep the 2 data I am interested in and so with one formula  
I hope it is makes more sense

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using excel or google spreadsheets, because some functions are somewhat different.

Comment: Google spreadsheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two columns giving you only the results you are looking for, use the following:

Assuming your data is in column J and row 1 is a header row, place this formula in row 2 of the column you wish to have the Status appear.  It will include all text to the first colon (:) :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISTEXT( J2:J),  IFERROR( REGEXEXTRACT(J2:J,"[^:]*")), ))
```

In the column where you want the YYYY to appear, this will grab everything from the last colon to the end:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISTEXT( J2:J),  IFERROR( REGEXEXTRACT(J2:J,"([^: ]*)$")), ))
```

The [ARRAYFORMULA()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) allows the formula to work on the column without copying the formula down to each cell.

[IFERROR()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) Keeps us from showing an error if a match is not found.

[REGEXTRACT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) returns the portion of the string matching the regular expression.  There are many examples of using these via a search, and [this GitHub is Google's reference on their use](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt).

Comment: Thanks. I will take it from there

Comment: I would suggest marking the question as answered if you think this suits your needs. You can do so by clicking on the tick right next to @Karl_s answer (if needed have a look at this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) )

Answer (score 0):

**Documentation and background**

I would suggest you to have a look at the functions to manipulate strings of character from the documentation of Google Docs:

[REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) to extract [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) from a string of character

[FIND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) to get the position of a word within a string of character

[MID](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129?hl=en) to get part of a string oof character

[LEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en) to get the length of a string of chracter

These functions are similar to Excel's one.

I would also add the link to the [regular expressions supported by Google docs](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt) so you can look in depth what the cases are.

**Implementation**

The idea is to have a column next to the formula in the spreadsheet, that would contain the keyword you are looking for. As such the desired worksheet would look like this:

[image]

What we then do is looking for the desired keyword in the column B and extract the next string of character with the pattern of `number/number/number` after the keyword input and before the next `and`.

**Solution**

Hence, the desired formula for the cell C1 would look like this :

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(MID($A$1;FIND(B1;$A$1);FIND("and";$A$1;FIND(B1;$A$1) + LEN(B1)));"[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+")
```

Note that you can drag the formula to the cells underneath and the function will look for the keyword within the cell A1.